# ruby ping for 1.9.1

Tags: ruby

I want to ping a site in my ruby code and saw that net-ping was a nice library to do this with. Unfortunately, when I tried to gem install net-ping I got the following error:

> C:>gem install net-ping
>   ERROR:  Error installing net-ping:
>           win32-open3 requires Ruby version < 1.9.0.

upon further research, I found that net-ping was not available yet for 1.9.X. Does anyone have a good piece of code that pings that they would be willing to share.

Comment: If you really need to do ICMP ping, you always can use native OS tool like ``ping -c 1 host`` and parse result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always do this and use regexps to parse the result or just check the exit status:

```
ping_count = 10
server = "www.google.com"
result = `ping -q -c #{ping_count} #{server}`
if ($?.exitstatus == 0) do
  puts "Device is up!"
end
```

Ping return values that you can check against:

> The ping utility returns an exit status of zero if at least one response was heard from  the specified host; a status of two if the transmission was successful but no responses were received; or another value (from `<sysexits.h>`) if an error occurred.

http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/ping

Comment: Just checking to see if a device is up before I run the rest of my code. Also, tried your code, how do I see the results of the ping?

Comment: This was the hint I needed to use `\`ping -t 1 ipinfodb.com\`` to have a working timeout in place and to find out if ipinfodb.com is online. Timeout and SystemTimer both didn't work somehow and waited full 60 seconds to throw an error. Thanks!

Comment: Shelling out to the OS for something as trivial as a ping is extraordinarily bad practice. This answer will fail under windows (as ping arguments and output format are different across different OS implementations). This is a particularly bad answer since the text of the question itself shows a "C:" prompt, clearly indicating a non-*nix environment.

Answer (score 15):

If by 'site' you mean website, then I wouldn't use ping. Ping will tell you if the host is up (unless a router or firewall is blocking ICMP), but it won't tell you if your web server or web app is responding properly.

If that's the case, I'd recommend Net::HTTP from the standard library, or any of the other HTTP libraries. One way to do it is:

```
def up?(site)
  Net::HTTP.new(site).head('/').kind_of? Net::HTTPOK
end

up? 'www.google.com' #=> true
```

Comment: Also site can deny non-browser requests. Compare www.habrahabr.ru and www.google.ru. So you need look into response more closely and/or play with user-agents.

Comment: I experienced problems with this code on windows, receiving a "Bad Gateway" for a working site. I could work around it using "get" instead of "head". Maybe this helps someone on windows.

Comment: @mit Sounds like you hit a proxy that wasn't to spec and couldn't handle 'HEAD' requests. Glad you got it working with `get`.

Answer (score 2):

For windows follow these instructions:

```
download djberg96-net-ping-net-ping-1.5.3-0-g9252076.zip from github.com/djberg96/net-ping
unzip, cd in the folder
gem build net-ping.gemspec
gem install net-ping-1.5.3-universal-mingw32.gem
gem install win32-security
```

to use it:

```
require 'net/ping'
p Net::Ping::TCP.new('www.google.com', 'http').ping?
p Net::Ping::TCP.new('foo.bar.baz').ping?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use from [source](https://github.com/djberg96/net-ping)

```
gem "net-ping", :git => 'git://github.com/djberg96/net-ping.git'
# bundle install
```

Now you can use functions from it in 1.9.2