# Checking if proxy is working in Ruby

Tags: ruby, proxy, ping

I'm new to Ruby and trying to find a way to check if a proxy is working. I've tried using the 'net/ping' library but I am just getting some errors while requiring it(in Interactive Ruby the script works even though there are the errors, it just closes itself when I run the script normally though)

I'm trying to find a solution to make it either ignore the error, fix the error or find another way to check if the proxy works.

Thanks for help.

This is the error message I get when I try to require the 'net/ping'

> proxy.rb(main):005:0> require 'net/ping'
>   LoadError: no such file to load -- windows/console
>           from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ping-1.5.2/lib/net/ping/ext
>   ernal.rb:12:in `require'
>           from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ping-1.5.2/lib/net/ping/ext
>   ernal.rb:12:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ping-1.5.2/lib/net/ping.rb:
>   10:in `require'
>           from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ping-1.5.2/lib/net/ping.rb:
>   10:in`'
>           from C:\Users\X\Desktop\proxy.rb:5:in `require'
>           from C:\Users\X\Desktop\proxy.rb:5
>           from C:/Ruby191/bin/irb:12:in`'

Comment: answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561669/ruby-ping-for-1-9-1

Comment: @three - that question related to checking if a website is up, a different proposition from checking if a proxy is working.

Comment: yes, why not make a request with ping through the proxy?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the only way to check if a proxy is working is to connect through it and make a request.